# Cannot see linked server properties in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I configured a linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2; mirroring what currently exists in SQL Server 2000.

When viewing the properties of an existing linked you, you cannot see (or edit) any information in 2008R2 - where you can in 2000

**Note**: This is different from the [unresolved bug where you cannot ***edit*** any details of a linked server in SQL Server 2008 R2 without it throwing an error.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/573861/editing-linked-server-properties-throws-ad-hoc-updates-error)

So, how do i fix SSMS?

---

- SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)
- SQL Server Management Studio: 10.50.2550.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure these fields have been non-editable since 2005 came out.  Scripting out the link and making the changes you want to the link is the way to go.  If you suspect it's a bug then you should put an entry on connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 2):

What I have done for this issue is script out the linked server where I can then see the properties defined within the script that is produced. This is a less then ideal solution but at the very least a work around so to what appears to be a problem in SSMS.